# How to solve a basic question about combinatorics

Tags: probability

> A family has 6 babies, what is the probability that:
>
> a) The second and forth are boys?
>
> b) The first and the last are girls?
>
> What are the total possibilities?

I know this should easy but I am not getting the answer, can I get some help?

The whole possibilities are $n^k$ = $2^6$ but the rest seems confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)Number of possibilities where the 2nd and 4th babies are boys = 2*1*2*1*2*2 = 16

So, probability of 2nd and 4th babies being boys = 16/64 = 1/4

b)Number of possibilities where the 1st and 6th babies are girls = 1*2*2*2*2*1 = 16

So, probability of 1st and 6th babies being girls = 16/64 = 1/4

A simpler way to look at this is ignoring the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 6th babies in part (a), since the genders of each baby are independent of the genders of the other babies. So, simply put, the required probability will be

P(baby1= boy or girl)*P(baby 3 = boy or girl)*P(baby 5 = boy or girl)*P(baby 6 = boy or girl)*P(baby 2 = boy)*P(baby 4 = boy) = 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4.

Similarly for part (b).

Answer (score 1):

> The whole possibilities are $n^k = 2^6$ but the rest seems confusing

Yes, there are $2^6$ possible outcomes for **six** *independent* choices from **two** options.

So for a favoured event where two of the six choices are specified, there are *how many* posibilities for the remaining **four** choices?